# Socket programming. Program creating 2 connections instead of just 1

Tags: java

I am building a client/server application, for some socket programming exercise.

Below is construction + run method of my server class. The server awaits a respond from the client, which in this case is just a string.

The problem is that it seems to make two connections when the client respond. From my print statements i can see that all the code in the run method is run twice, and then the first line once again.

Why would dateServer.accept(); accept a connection for only one client request?

```
public Server() throws Exception {
    dateServer = new ServerSocket(3001);
    System.out.println("Server lytter på port 3000.");
    this.start();
}


 public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("waiting for client to request");
            Socket client = dateServer.accept();
            System.out.println("connection established");
            Connect c = new Connect(client);
            clients.add(c);
            this.sleep(5000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

--EDIT--
Client code that talks to server (Message is a simple "wrapper" class"):

```
System.out.println("Write to server:");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    Message message = new Message(name, null);
    oos.writeObject(message);
    oos.flush();
```

Comment: Show us the client-side code that tries to establish the connection. Is it running twice for some reason?

Comment: I have added the interesting code from the client

Comment: And it is ONE client trying to establish ONE connection

Comment: If the prints all print twice, there are two connections. No two ways about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the prints happen twice there must have been two connections. The first line prints again after that because you're in a loop.

NB:

1. *Never* ignore exceptions: especially IOExceptions.
2. The sleep is completely pointless. accept() will block while there are no incoming connections. You are literally wasting time here.

Comment: The sleep was just to try to figure out the cause of the error. It should have been deleted yes. Any suggestions to what could be wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the server. The client is connecting twice, or there is another client.

Comment: @Anders Put E.printStackTrace() in your exception clause and see if it throws anything

Comment: no difference :/ oh well guess i can ask my teacher tomorrrow thanks anyway